# Get unread emails from exchange in Windows 8 Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, exchangewebservices

I want to write an App (Windows Store App) which should display all my unread emails. I did my research at google and msdn but found nothing suitable.

The problem is as follow, my development pc does not have any connection to a exchange server, so I had to write an app (C#/XAML) which should later on work:

1. On every PC in the organisation
2. Uses the default credentials of the user
3. Displays the unread emails

Is it possible to get these information (Emails) by asking the EWS?
Is there a WinRT compatible Library to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is an api called EWS Managed API i don't know it is supported by WinRT or not.

Comment: This API (Library) is not supported by WinRT.

Comment: I dnt know much about WinRT but can you write code for send soap request to any server ? if yes then you can use that

Comment: I also tried this with an instance of the HttpClient class. But all the time I tried to call SendAsync or PostAsync my Visual Studio reported an Exception telling me "The underlying connection has been closed". (I did not have disposed the instance ;) )

Comment: You have Exchange server 2007,2010,2013 ? if yes then try to open https://yourDomain/ews/exchange.asmx it will ask for password, please check that you have successfully setup exchange server ?

Comment: No problems on the exchange config. if I open it with Visual Studio (Web Reference), Soap UI, etc. Only the HttpClient instance will not send data. Breaks on send with the error message written before.

Comment: Thanks@all, but I did not find any good solution to do this directly so I used a [proxy webservice to get my unread mails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011110/passing-networkcredentials-object-through-wcf-service-to-webservice-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found any good solution to request the Exchange Webservice from my Windows Store App.

The only solution I have now implemented was to use a own webservice which can use the [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to send requests to the Exchange Server *(higher than 2007)*.

The Windows Store App itself communicates via WCF with my *Proxy*-Webservice like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011110/passing-networkcredentials-object-through-wcf-service-to-webservice-c-sharp)